# Versão de classe em java

Tags: java, versionamento, documentação

Gostaria de saber se em java tem como eu especificar uma tag, ou manifest, ou algo do tipo para uma classe ou biblioteca e  conseguir consultar isso dentro do próprio código Java
tipo :

```
@version 2.6.5
Class Pessoa {
...
}
```

e la em uma outra parte do codigo

```
if (Class.getVersion(Pessoa) < 2.7)
{
   mensage.Aviso("Biblioteca de Pessoas em uma versão antiga. Atualize-o");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Desconheço algo que atenda o que deseja e também não consigo ver uma utilidade nisso. A pergunta é você realmente precisa disso? Se você quiser versionar sua classe você pode usar **git**, **mercurial** ou **svn**. Além disso o que é possível fazer é verificar a partir de um .class qual o minor e major version do Java em que sua classe foi compilada.

```
java -verbose MyClass
```

Mas se ainda deseja algo como o que postou, você mesmo pode criar uma Annotation e fazer uma lógica.

Comment: preciso disso para updates automáticos das bibliotecas, caso a versão seja inferior ao que se possui no FTP seria atualizado

Comment: existe como eu criar minhas próprias tags, correto? acho que vou criar para implementar essa funcionalidade.   Queria algo pronto.... mas como não tem... =/

Comment: Veja, da maneira que você deseja não conheço algo pronto. Mas se você precisa disso para controlar versão das bibliotecas, porque não usar maven para isso? Você usa ou conheçe?

Comment: uso somente pra resolver dependências, controlar versão não tinha visto ainda

Comment: Então você pode usá-lo para esse fim também. Você pode definiar dentro da tag <dependencyManagement></dependencyManagement> (pom.xml) e especificar a versão de cada lib.